# Как изменить тип MessageBox?

Tags: c++-cli

Привет всем!

Как изменить тип окна MessageBox на FixedToolWindow?

```
MessageBox::Show( "MSG", "MSG", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Exclamation );
```

Можно это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Напрямую к сожалению никак, но можно сделать посредством хуков, отлавливая момент создания окна MessageBox.

Более детально и с примером: [How to change the MessageBox window (Add controls and change texts)?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10037/How-to-change-the-MessageBox-window-Add-controls-a)

Также на CodeProject есть ряд других материалов по данной теме.