# Как изменить названия кнопок в MessageBox в C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

Как можно изменить названия кнопок в MessageBox в C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никак. Но можно создать форму нужных размеров, повесить там кнопки, информацию (label), и открывать её как `MessageBox` по виду, единственное лишний код будет, `MessageBox` для того и придуман что бы одной строчкой её показать и что-то так написать.

**Открыть форму можно так:**

```
Form form = new Form1();
form.ShowDialog();
```

На это форме помещаешь кнопку и обработчик.

**Закрыть форму:**

```
form.Close();
```

Answer (score 5):

Не соглашусь с ответами Василия и johniek_comp, возможность изменить тексты кнопок MessageBox есть. Совсем недавно был подобный вопрос ([Как изменить тип MessageBox?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/111620/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-messagebox?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=111624#111624)).

В случае с кнопками реализация почти ничем не отличается - нужно поставить hook и отлавливать момент создания окна MessageBox и его внутренних контролов.

На CodeProject есть готовый пример по изменению текстов кнопок MessageBox на C#: [Localizing System MessageBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18399/Localizing-System-MessageBox)

Comment: я не говорил что нельзя, я сказал что стандартно нет, а так то можно изменить вообще все в C#, было бы желание

Comment: Это выглядит как overkill

Comment: Очень круто. Не знал о такой возможности. Спасибо за ссылки в ответе, полезно, не знал.

Answer (score 4):

Класс MessageBox является оберткой над вызовом функции Windows API MessageBox и как таковой не позволяет менять названия кнопок. Вам потребуется создать свой собственный диалог и уже в него добавить необходимые кнопки.