# Изменение название кнопок в QMessageBox

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Можно как нибудь изменить название используемых кнопок в `QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question` или в [`QMessageBox.`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#StandardButton-enum) что то вроде заместо `yes, no` было бы `да, нет`. Прочитал [подобный вопрос только на C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/111774/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-messagebox-%D0%B2-c), там написано что нужно создать отдельную форму для `QDialog` правда вопрос задавался аж в 2012 году может сейчас уже это стало возможным

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QMessageBox, QApplication


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.show()


    def closeEvent(self, event):

        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
            "Вы действительно хотите выйти?", QMessageBox.Yes |
            QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: связанный вопрос [Qt: how to translate the buttons in qmessagebox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31533019/4279)

Comment: @jfs т.е. как я понял без создания отдельного `QDialog` это сделать нельзя ? Потому как это реализовать в `python` не совсем понятно

Comment: я не вижу QDialog в принятом ответе. Это намекает какой ответ на ваш вопрос должен быть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из способов реализовать данное действие это создать отдельный [`QDialog`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html) и в нем прописать название кнопок.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        def closed():
            self.reply.close()
            event.ignore()

        self.reply = QDialog()
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        label_dialog = QLabel()
        label_dialog.setText('Вы действительно хотите выйти?')
        button_yes = QPushButton(self.reply)
        button_yes.setText("Да")
        button_yes.clicked.connect(lambda: self.reply.close())
        button_no = QPushButton(self.reply)
        button_no.setText('Нет')
        button_no.clicked.connect(closed)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button_yes)
        layout.addWidget(button_no)
        vbox.addWidget(label_dialog)
        vbox.addSpacing(20)
        vbox.addLayout(layout)
        self.reply.setLayout(vbox)
        self.reply.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Так же можно и таким способом группируя кнопки методом [`QButtonGroup`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html) после чего по `id_name` выбирать нажатия кнопки и ее действие

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        def check_button(id_name):
            if button_group.id(id_name) == 1:
                reply.close()
                event.accept()
            elif button_group.id(id_name) == 2:
                reply.close()
                event.ignore()

        reply = QDialog()
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        label_dialog = QLabel()
        label_dialog.setText('Вы действительно хотите выйти?')
        button_yes = QPushButton(reply)
        button_yes.setText("Да")
        button_no = QPushButton(reply)
        button_no.setText('Нет')
        button_group = QButtonGroup()
        button_group.addButton(button_yes, 1)
        button_group.addButton(button_no, 2)
        button_group.buttonClicked.connect(check_button)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button_yes)
        layout.addWidget(button_no)
        vbox.addWidget(label_dialog)
        vbox.addSpacing(20)
        vbox.addLayout(layout)
        reply.setLayout(vbox)
        reply.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно с помощью QMessageBox.

```
QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setText(tr("Confirm?"));
QAbstractButton* pButtonYes = msgBox.addButton(tr("Да!"), QMessageBox::YesRole);
msgBox.addButton(tr("Нет"), QMessageBox::NoRole);

msgBox.exec();

if (msgBox.clickedButton()==pButtonYes) 
{
  //Execute command
}
```

Взято https://wiki.qt.io/Custom_QMessageBox_Buttons