# QMessageBox перевод кнопок

Tags: c++, qt

Как в таком примере перевести кнопки с `YES/NO` на свой текст либо загрузке файла с переводом

```
QMessageBox::StandardButton reply;
    reply = QMessageBox::warning(this, "Programm beenden?", "Soll das Programm wirklich beendet werden?",
                                  QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);

    if (reply == QMessageBox::Yes)
    {
        if(wasOpen == 0)
        {
            QMessageBox(QMessageBox::Critical, tr("Flugprotokoll unvollständig ausgefüllt"), tr("Bitte füllen Sie das Flugprotokoll vollständig aus, bevor Sie das Programm beenden"), QMessageBox::Ok).exec();
        }else{
            QApplication::quit();
        }
    }else{

    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Изменение название кнопок в QMessageBox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766152/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-qmessagebox)

Comment: @Twiss сравнивать с++ и питон вопросы...

Comment: Модуль `qt` один. Так же на [C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/111774/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-messagebox-%d0%b2-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Так же если вас так мучает что это `python` , а не `c++` вот вам такой же вопрос на английском https://stackoverflow.com/q/31533019/8206722

Comment: В таком примере сделать это нельзя. Нужно создавать объект QMessageBox и там уже будет доступ к тексту кнопок. Буквально вчера делал это

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTranslator qtTranslator;
    if (qtTranslator.load(QLocale::system(),
                "qt", "_",
                QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath)))
    {
        qDebug() << "qtTranslator ok";
        app.installTranslator(&qtTranslator);
    }

    QTranslator qtBaseTranslator;
    if (qtBaseTranslator.load("qtbase_" + QLocale::system().name(),
                QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath)))
    {
        qDebug() << "qtBaseTranslator ok";
        app.installTranslator(&qtBaseTranslator);
    }

    QMessageBox::question(0, QObject::tr("Sure want to quit?"), QObject::tr("Sure to quit?"), QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Упрощенный пример:

```
QMessageBox messageBox(QMessageBox::Question,
            tr("Sure want to quit?"),
            tr("Sure to quit?"),
            QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No,
            this);
    messageBox.setButtonText(QMessageBox::Yes, tr("Yes"));
    messageBox.setButtonText(QMessageBox::No, tr("No"));
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533019/title-qt-how-to-translate-the-buttons-in-qmessagebox/31533126

Comment: тут он берет перевод основываясь на языке системы, а как указать самому какой файл с переводом он должен взять?

Comment: @Insider Вот тут есть пример установки языка приложения, который берётся из файлов локализации: http://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_multi_language_application